# How do I disable spring security in a Grails 4 integration test?

Tags: spring-boot, grails, spring-security, integration-testing, grails-4

I had a grails 3 app including spring security, which I recently upgraded to grails 4.

My `application.yml` includes the following:

```
environments:
    test:
        grails:
            plugin:
                springsecurity:
                    active: false
        security:
            ignored: '/**'
            basic:
                enabled: false
        spring:
            security:
                enabled: false
```

Why doesn't this work in Grails 4? What's a good alternative solution?

Grails 4 seems to be ignoring this configuration. When I run integration tests, I am getting a 403 error with a message:

`Could not verify the provided CSRF token because your session was not found.`

It seems like spring security enabled, and it's using `SecurityFilterAutoConfiguration`, which is normally excluded for my app.

**Update**

I am using the following dependencies:

```
    compile('org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.2.3') {
        exclude group: 'org.springframework.security'
    }
    compile ('org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:4.2.13.RELEASE') {
        force = true
    }
    compile 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:4.2.13.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:4.2.13.RELEASE'
```

**Update 2:**

In my debugger, I found that the spring security core plugin actually *is* being disabled. The following code from the plugin class is executed:

```
SpringSecurityUtils.resetSecurityConfig()
        def conf = SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig
        boolean printStatusMessages = (conf.printStatusMessages instanceof Boolean) ? conf.printStatusMessages : true
        if (!conf || !conf.active) {
            if (printStatusMessages) {
                // <-- the code in this block is executed; active flag is false
                String message = '\n\nSpring Security is disabled, not loading\n\n'
                log.info message
                println message
            }
            return
        }
```

...however, I am still getting the CSRF filter error, so Spring Security must be configuring itself somehow regardless.

**Update 3:**

The CSRF filter is being set up by `ManagementWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`, using the default configuration.

I tried adding the following to `resources.groovy`:

```
    if (grailsApplication.config.disableSecurity == true && !Environment.isWarDeployed()) {
        webSecurityConfigurerAdapter(new WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter(true) {})
    }
```

This did not fix the issue. Although my anonymous WSCA bean is being constructed, the MWSCA default bean is still being used by spring.

Comment: What version of the spring security plugin are you using?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The grails plugin version is 3.2.3. I have added a snippet from my gradle dependencies to the OP.

Comment: With Grails 4 you are going to want to use 4.x of the plugin.  At the moment I think 4.0.0 may be the latest.

Comment: Did you try the following one in Config.groovy? grails.plugin.springsecurity.active = false

Comment: @JeffScottBrown I think I tried this if I remember correctly, and found that the plugin requires a new major version of spring security, which isn't compatible with library code I'm using from another team. I wasn't able to get the other team to update that library. I can take it up with them again if no other fix is available, but it could be a few months before I get an update.

Comment: @Dashzeveg I think Config.groovy was removed in Grails 3. I can try to put this setting in my application.yml and see if it picks it up.

Comment: " I can try to put this setting in my application.yml and see if it picks it up." - The original question includes "My application.yml includes the following".  I thought you already had the settings there.

Comment: @RMorrisey I'm sorry. I mistook the config file name of grails 4. I meant that you need to try the following code in application.groovy. grails.plugin.springsecurity.active = false

Comment: It seems spring-security-config isn't needed in a project using the grails plugin? After I removed that from my path, it seemed to fix the issue. I'm not sure it's OK to do this? I'll be testing my app thoroughly in dev to make sure it's still secure.

Comment: I also determined that most of the spring security-related properties settings no longer apply in the new version of spring boot.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in

> **grails-app/conf/application.groovy**

```
environments {
    development {

    }
    test {
        grails.plugin.springsecurity.active = false
    }
    production {

    }
}
```

Comment: @JeffScottBrown is correct, this setting is already in the YML files for my app